# What is the equivalent of Type.GetGenericArguments() in .NETStandard 1.0 / .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

The method `System.Type.GetGenericArguments()` is 'missing' from .NETStandard 1.0, and I thought that the `TypeInfo.GenericTypeArguments` was the replacement for `GetGenericArguments()`, but unfortuntely they behave differently when supplied with an open generic type. Take for instance the following code:

```
Type type = typeof(ICommandHandler<>);
type.GetGenericArguments(); // return { TCommand }
type.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments; // returns empty array
```

While the `GetGenericArguments()` method returns the generic type argument `TCommand`, the `GenericTypeArguments` simply returns an empty array for the same open-generic type.

What is the exact behavior of `GenericTypeArguments` and what's the equivalent of `Type.GetGenericArguments()` in .NET Standard 1.0?

Comment: @DavidL: .NETStandard is a [he .NET Standard Library is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET runtimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library). .NET 1.0 is ooooold, while .NETStandard is new; the new PCL to be more precise.

Comment: Note one is a standard, and one is an implementation of the standard. From the article: " .NET Core 1.0 implements the .NET Standard Library 1.6"

Comment: Additionally, according to that chart, the only implementation of .NET Standard 1.0 was Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0.

Comment: Do you have `.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters`?

Comment: Since you are giving the type as `ICommandHandler<>`, there are no generic type arguments. If you had given it `ICommandHandler<string>` though, you would have an item in that array.

Comment: I'm 80% sure you are looking at missing functionality.  Yes, ought to throw an exception, consider filing a bug report.

Comment: @HansPassant, my question is: what method or property should I call to get the same behavior, since the new property is clearly not what I require.

Comment: No good alternative for missing functionality.  Reflection in .NETCore is due for a big overhaul btw, I generally have to recommend anybody to wait for the proverbial version 3 when Microsoft always gets it right.

Comment: Just a FYI, .Net Core 1.0 is netstandard 1.6 not 1.0. Netstandard 1.0 is pre .net 4.5, compatible with Windows phone 8 only. .net 4.6.2 is netstandard 1.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After further investigation, the `Type.GenericTypeArguments` seems to only return anything if the type isn't a generic type definition. The `TypeInfo.GenericTypeParameters` on the other hand, only returns any if the type is a generic type definition.

The following code mimics the behavior of `Type.GetGenericArguments()`:

```cs
type.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericTypeDefinition 
    ? type.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters 
    : type.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments;
```

Answer (score 4):

This may turn out to be a comment (not an answer) after all.

On .NET 4.6.1, there are two members on `System.Type`, namely:

```
/* 1 */ type.GetGenericArguments()               // returns { TCommand, }

/* 2 */ type.GenericTypeArguments                // returns empty array
```

plus one member on `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`, namely:

```
/* 3 */ type.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters // returns { TCommand, }
```

for a total of **three** members.

However, the two first-mentioned members are also *inherited* by `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`, a subclass of `System.Type`.

On .NET 4.6.1, when you do `type.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments` (as in your question), you really call the property on `Type`, i.e. my member marked `/* 2 */`.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. Any idea how to get the open generic type arguments under .NET Standard 1.0?

Comment: @Steven No, unfortunately not. If I understand Scott Chamberlain's comment to your question correctly, there might be a chance this can inspire someone to a solution for .NET Standard 1.5 (_edit:_ maybe even .NET Standard 1.1) or later. How confusing to have three names `GetGenericArguments()`, `GenericTypeArguments`, and `GenericTypeParameters`. In some senses Microsoft .NET Framework has become messy. Is the purpose of ".NET Standard" (also) to tidy up things like this?