# How can I get the number of type parameters on an open generic in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

In short this pretty much explains my problem ...

```
class Foo<T> { ... }
var type = typeof(Foo<>); <-- runtime provides a RuntimeType object instance in my real code
var paramCount = ((RuntimeType)type).GetGenericParameters().Count; <-- I need this
```

The problem of course is that "RuntimeType" is an internal type in (I believe) mscorlib, so I can't access it from my code.

Is there another / better way to do this?

Update:

I found an "ugly and probably unsafe" way to achieve basically what I need but i'm convinced it's a bad idea (for obvious reasons) ...

```
var paramCount = int.Parse(type.Name.Substring(t.Name.Length-1));
```

This is assuming quite a bit and just feels nasty.
that said ... i'm already in reflection world ... so it's nasty by nature.

Surely there's a better way to do this though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the full .NET then you can simply:

```
int num = type.GetGenericArguments().Length;
```

If you are using .NET Core then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39140220/613130:

```
TypeInfo typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
int num = typeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    ? typeInfo.GenericTypeParameters.Length
    : typeInfo.GenericTypeArguments.Length;
```

If you always have an open generic then clearly:

```
int num = type.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters.Length;
```

Comment: @War If you are using the full .NET then `type.GetGenericArguments().Length;` will work. You don't need casting. the `type` variable should be declared as a `Type type`. `RuntimeType` is something internal that you can ignore.

Comment: ah nice .. .thanks man :) ... just needed to pull in System.reflection ... yeh I think this is a full .Net thing only ... won't work for Core